# cloudfoundry : space sharing approach with multiple developers

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

with the cloudfoundary landscape on sap cloud platform , i was looking at approach / best practise when multiple developers work on the same app.

Should each developer have a seperate space and must push the app each time  they want test ?
or

Should there be one "devopment" space with multiple apps and some kind of service sharing among the different apps that each developer will push ? . In this approch i do see the issues if i change a service (eg db) that might effect other apps that share it.

I went through the documentation but did not get any hints about multiple developers working in the space , so any advice / experiences is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone can tell you what makes sense for your organization. You need to think about how you want to organize your users, applications & spaces. Quota management plays into this, but so does access to apps & services.

Things to consider:

1. Who needs access to the apps you're putting into the space? You can control this with the space roles (space dev, manager & auditor).
2. How to you want to manage the spaces? This is going to give you some insight into how you want to structure your orgs. Org permissions allow an operator to delegate management to someone else (org manager, auditor roles).
3. How do you need to be able to restrict the resources that your uses consume? i.e. quotas. You can apply quotas to orgs & spaces. Consider how you want to restrict what groups can do.
4. Consider org/space boundaries. Will you have need to share things like services across orgs & spaces? There is some capacity to do this through the foundation, but be careful because individual service brokers need to support this also. At the time of writing some do and some do not. Those that do not would need to be shared with the must less convenient user provided service.

   https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html
5. Consider if you need to do billing or charge-back. Doing this per org/space makes sense, so you would need to align that with how you're doing billing/charge-back.

I wouldn't suggest adopting one of these strategies without thinking it through first, but here are a couple examples of what I've seen people do.

1. In teams where the developers manage throughout the full cycle, I've seen orgs be used to group development teams and spaces use to group project or apps. Thus team A has access to org A, which has spaces X, Y and Z for App X, Y and Z. App X, Y and Z deploy dev, test, qa and prod into the same space.
2. In companies with more traditional structures where dev teams pass off code to an ops team, I typically see orgs and spaces to facilitate that separation. Devs have their own orgs & spaces for development & testing. Ops has their own orgs and spaces for production. The two do not mix.

There are also variations on this, so again think through what makes sense for you and your company.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Daniel that makes a lot of sence

Answer (score 0):

The spaces on Cloud Foundry have the functional purpose of providing quota management and control management to a group of people. As such, you should structure the spaces, depending on your need to isolate/control applications.

The most common use case for spaces are:
- dev / qua / prod
- department_a  / deparment_b;..

Regarding the development of shared services, please make sure you understand about CF services, they provided different mechanism from regular apps, for example, a service instance (like a DB), can be shared between different applications on different spaces:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html